# Black tty 1-6 screens

Tags: 10.04, drivers, upgrade

After installing Ubuntu 10.04 I had some flickering issues, so I tried upgrading drivers and such, then I installed the `fglrx` driver and the flickering have gone away but when trying to access the TTY screens from 1-6 the screen goes blank. I'm able to get back in to gnome on tty7.

any one have a suggestion on what to try here?

---

**Dennis**

the output is:

glennwiz@Linux-laptop:~$ sudo cat /dev/vcs1

```
Ubuntu 10.04.1 LTS Linux-laptop tty1

Linux-laptop login:
```

**Nerdfest** im using radeon x1300

```
lspci output
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express Memory Controller Hub (rev 03)
00:01.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Mobile 945GM/PM/GMS, 943/940GML and 945GT Express PCI Express Root Port (rev 03)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family High Definition Audio Controller (rev 01)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 1 (rev 01)
00:1c.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 2 (rev 01)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family PCI Express Port 4 (rev 01)
00:1d.0 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH7 Family USB UHCI Controller #1 (rev 01)
00:1d.1 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #2 (rev 01)
00:1d.2 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #3 (rev 01)
00:1d.3 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB UHCI Controller #4 (rev 01)
00:1d.7 USB Controller: Intel Corporation N10/ICH 7 Family USB2 EHCI Controller (rev 01)
00:1e.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 82801 Mobile PCI Bridge (rev e1)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82801GBM (ICH7-M) LPC Interface Bridge (rev 01)
00:1f.2 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82801GBM/GHM (ICH7 Family) SATA IDE Controller (rev 01)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: ATI Technologies Inc M52 [Mobility Radeon X1300]
02:06.0 CardBus bridge: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 Cardbus Controller
02:06.2 Mass storage controller: Texas Instruments 5-in-1 Multimedia Card Reader (SD/MMC/MS/MS PRO/xD)
02:06.3 SD Host controller: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 SDA Standard Compliant SD Host Controller
02:06.4 Communication controller: Texas Instruments PCIxx12 GemCore based SmartCard controller
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation NetXtreme BCM5753M Gigabit Ethernet PCI Express (rev 21)
10:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation PRO/Wireless 3945ABG [Golan] Network Connection (rev 02)
```

---

Anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know this thread has been dead for quite a while now, but the problem may still exist for some of you, as it did for me until some moments ago.
Here is how to get your tty-consoles back if you just get black screens after hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F6</kbd>:

1. In a console, run

   ```
   sudo apt-get install v86d
   ```
2. When installation finishes, open:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/default/grub
   ```
3. Find the line that reads:

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet"
   ```

   *Note: there may be more entries between the ""s, depending on previous changes.*

   Replace it with (or expand accordingly):

   ```
   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet nomodeset video=uvesafb:mode_option=1280x1024-24,mtrr=3,scroll=ywrap"
   ```
4. Find another line which reads:

   ```
   #GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480
   ```

   And replace it with:

   ```
   GRUB_GFXMODE=1280x1024
   ```

   Note: be sure there's no `#` in front.
5. Save and close the editor.
6. Now open:

   ```
   gksudo gedit /etc/initramfs-tools/modules
   ```

   At the end of the file, add the line:

   ```
   uvesafb mode_option=1280x1024-24 mtrr=3 scroll=ywrap
   ```
7. Save and close the editor.
8. Finally run:

   ```
   FRAMEBUFFER=y | sudo tee /etc/initramfs-tools/conf.d/splash && sudo update-grub2 && sudo update-initramfs -u
   ```
9. Now reboot. After reboot, your tty-consoles should be accessible again.

**Source: [crunchbanglinux.org: How to fix tty1-6 (Ctrl+Alt+Fx terminals) if they are not working](http://crunchbanglinux.org/forums/topic/8883/how-to-fix-tty16-ctrlaltfx-terminals-if-they-are-not-working/)**

Answer (score 1):

Per [this answer on another site](https://superuser.com/questions/168740/ubuntu-10-04-ati-mobility-radeon-x1300-screen-flickering-in-dark-areas/168764#168764):

> I needed to create the file
>   `/etc/modprobe.d/radeon-kms.conf`, add
>   following line
>
> ```
> options radeon modeset=0
> ```
>
> and had to restart. Now flickering is
>   gone. :)

Comment: tested this had no effect. flickerign still is there with the native drivers.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that I had that problem a couple of years ago with a computer running an ATI card. IIRC the solution was to give the kernel a different resolution in the boot options.

You can try to add a vga=785 to your boot command. If you hit SHIFT while Ubuntu is starting to load, you should be able to see a GRUB menu. Press 'e' and you must be able to edit the boot command. At the end of the line that starts with "*linux*" append vga=785 at the end. Hit CTRL+X to boot.

You can try with some other resolutions, you can find instructions to create mode numbers in this [wiki](http://wiki.antlinux.com/pmwiki.php?n=HowTos.VgaModes).

Note that I can't check this and it's based in my very flawed memory. Hope that it works. Don't hesitate to downvote it if it is just a too wild guess.

Comment: tested, but same problem :/ thx for helping tho :)