# Every tty (Ctrl+Alt+F1-6) shows a black screen

Tags: drivers, radeon, amd-graphics

When I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>-<kbd>6</kbd>, a black screen is the result. The tty is not off-screen, I tried to hold down letters to check that, but it's not the issue, it simply stays all black. I can switch back to the GUI (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>) with no problems.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS with an AMD Radeon R9 270X GPU.

Here is the output of `lspci`:

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Curacao XT [Radeon R9 270X]
```

And I use the fglrx drivers provided by Ubuntu:

```
$ fglrxinfo
display: :0  screen: 0
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon R9 200 Series   
OpenGL version string: 4.4.13374 Compatibility Profile Context 15.20.1013
```

I tried to find some related errors in `dmesg` but nothing interesting here related to fglrx:

```
$ dmesg | grep fglrx
[   11.277446] fglrx: module license 'Proprietary. (C) 2002 - ATI Technologies, Starnberg, GERMANY' taints kernel.
[   11.284297] fglrx: module verification failed: signature and/or  required key missing - tainting kernel
[   11.297733] <6>[fglrx] Maximum main memory to use for locked dma buffers: 15638 MBytes.
[   11.297960] <6>[fglrx]   vendor: 1002 device: 6810 revision: 0 count: 1
[   11.298364] <6>[fglrx] ioport: bar 4, base 0xe000, size: 0x100
[   11.298619] <6>[fglrx] Kernel PAT support is enabled
[   11.298631] <6>[fglrx] module loaded - fglrx 15.20.2 [Feb 27 2015] with 1 minors
[   18.778958] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1397
[   18.779024] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1398
[   18.779087] <6>[fglrx] Firegl kernel thread PID: 1399
[   18.779176] <6>[fglrx] IRQ 33 Enabled
[   18.789875] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Shared offset:0, size:1000000 
[   18.789877] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f7b4000, size:4000 
[   18.789878] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:f7b8000, size:548000 
[   18.789880] <6>[fglrx] Reserved FB block: Unshared offset:7ffee000, size:12000
```

I have tried this guide: [Black tty 1-6 screens](https://askubuntu.com/questions/3667/black-tty-1-6-screens) but it did not help. Still got black tty's.

How can I fix it?